# In appium maintain the section of the service and driver

Tags: appium-android

I am using appium with cucumber framework.
Before each scenario, I needed to call the login scenario for the app. If the login scenario is not called before each scenario then the scenario fails and throws the errors. Instead of calling login scenario each time before each scenario how to call login scenario once and run the rest of the scenario without calling login before each scenario. Please find the code below. Run login scenario once and run rest of the scenario without calling login again still the scenario in a feature file ends. please find the error below when running login scenario once and continue with other scenario.

Error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at StepDefinations.AddCustomersSteps.user_click_on_customer_button(AddCustomersSteps.java:27)
   at ✽.user click on Customer 
   button(file:///H:/SeleniumWorkSpace/PosApp/src/test/resources/Features/AddCustomers.feature:18)

   java.lang.NullPointerException
   at StepDefinations.Hooks.getBase64Screenshot(Hooks.java:75)
   at StepDefinations.Hooks.AfterStepScreenShot(Hooks.java:65)
```

Feature file:

```
@AddCustomer
Feature: Add customer details and verify added Customer 

Background: Check login into with Valid credential and Valid Pin

Given User Launch App 
And Select the radio button for Stand Alone mode 
And Click on Done button
And user enter details
And user clicks on login
Then user navigate to the Home page
And user is on location selection page and select a location
And user enter valid pin "1234"

Scenario Outline: Verify the Adding new customer details and search the new added customer

Given user is on the app Home page
And user click on Customer button
When user enter the fields for <firstname> <lastname> <mobile> <email> <address> <landmark> <pincode> 
And User click on add customer button
Then Validate the customer added successfully <name>
Examples:
|firstname|lastname|mobile    |email           |address|landmark|pincode|name         |
|robert   |ggggg  |1234567891|robert@gmail.com|11-574 |tvc   |685002 |rrtyyu ttttt|


Scenario Outline: Verify the Adding Collection details

Given user is on the app Home page
And user click on Collection button
When user enter the collection details <name> <phone> <email> <note>
And user select date and time
And User click on ok button for collection
Then Validate the delivery details added for customer
Examples:
|name            |phone      |email           |note         |
|rtyuur jikrkrkrk   |1234567891 |ruuuu@gmail.com|Added details|
```

Driver

```
package Utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;

public class DriverManager extends Interact
{

public AppiumDriverLocalService service;
public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver;
        
public AppiumDriverLocalService startServer()
{

//To check if the server is running or it is closed using below function
boolean flag = checkIfServerIsRunning(4723);

if(!flag)
{
service =AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
service.start();

}//flag

return service;
        
}//startServer

public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities(String appName) throws IOException, 
InterruptedException 
{

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
"\\src\\test\\resources\\Resources\\global.properties");
Properties pro = new Properties();
pro.load(fis);  
    
File appDir = new File("src");
File app = new File(appDir, (String) pro.get(appName));
URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


 String device = (String) pro.get("device");

 //Run the device through command
//Maven command => mvn test -DdeviceName=RobertEmulator
//String device = System.getProperty("deviceName");

if(device.contains("TabEmulator"))
{
    
startEmulator();
    
}//Emulator

capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,"Android");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, device);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,14);
capabilities.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));

capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(url,capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
return driver;  

}//Capabilities
```

Hooks

```
package StepDefinations;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter;
import Utils.Interact;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.AfterStep;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;


public class Hooks extends Interact
{

 public static String screenshotdir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/screenshots/";

 //Start Appium Server Programmatically before each scenario
 @Before
 public void Initialization() throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {
    
 //If port is blocked run the below command to terminate the port 
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
 Thread.sleep(3000L);

 if ((new File(screenshotdir)).exists())
 FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(screenshotdir));

 }//Initialization 

 @After
 public void quit() 
 {

 if(getDriver() != null) 
 {

 getDriver().quit();

 }//getDriver

 if(getService() != null) 
 {

 getService().stop();

 }//if

 }//quit


 @AfterStep
 public void AfterStepScreenShot(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException, IOException 
 {

 if(scenario.isFailed())
 {
 ExtentCucumberAdapter.addTestStepScreenCaptureFromPath(getBase64Screenshot());
 ExtentCucumberAdapter.addTestStepLog("Screenshot attached");
 }//isFailed

 }//AfterStepScreenShot
```

LoginStep

```
 package StepDefinations;
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 import com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter;

 import Context.TestContextUI;
 import Utils.DriverManager;
 import Utils.Interact;
 import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
 import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
 import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

 public class LoginSteps extends Interact 
 {


 DriverManager driverManager = new DriverManager();
 public AppiumDriverLocalService service;
 public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>  driver;
 TestContextUI testContextUI;

 public LoginSteps(TestContextUI testContextUI)
 {

 this.testContextUI = testContextUI;

 }//LoginSteps


 @Given("^User Launch App$")
 public void user_launch_app() throws Throwable 
 {

service = driverManager.startServer();  
driver = driverManager.Capabilities("PosApp");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
setDriver(driver);
setService(service);
testContextUI.setService(service);
testContextUI.setDriver(driver);
testContextUI.intitializePageObject(driver,service);
ExtentCucumberAdapter.addTestStepLog("User Lauch the Apps");


}//user_launch_app

@When("^Select the radio button for Stand Alone mode$")
public void select_the_radio_button_for_stand_alone_mode() throws Throwable 
{



testContextUI.getLoginPage().ClickOnStandAloneButton();

}//select_the_radio_button_for_stand_alone_mode
```

AddCustomerSteps

```
 package StepDefinations;
 import org.junit.Assert;

 import Context.TestContextUI;
 import Utils.Interact;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
 import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

 public class AddCustomersSteps extends Interact
 {


 TestContextUI testContextUI;

 public AddCustomersSteps(TestContextUI testContextUI)
 {
    
 this.testContextUI = testContextUI;

 }//AddCustomersSteps

 @And("^user click on Customer button$")
 public void user_click_on_customer_button() throws Throwable 
 {

 testContextUI.getHomePage().ClickOnCustomerButton();  

 }//user_click_on_customer_button
```